# Python: Using RLock with multiple threads

Tags: python

The expected output should be for all 3 func() processes to complete and for 'finished' to not be printed, but instead test() returns `finished` after the first print(i) in func().

```
rlock = threading.RLock()

def func(): 
    rlock.acquire()
    for i in range(3): 
        time.sleep(2)
        print(i)
    rlock.release()
    return

def test(): 
    l = []
    for i in range(3): 
        time.sleep(1)
        threading.Thread(target=func).start() 
    print(rlock) # prints <_thread.RLock owner=140092805895936 count=1>
    print(rlock._is_owned()) #prints False 
    if not rlock._is_owned(): 
        return 'finished' #returns 'finished'

test()
```

Update: specifically I would like to have a `test()` function that does not return until all threads in `rlock` are finished. But I'm having trouble determining whether the rlock counter is incremented or not  - there doesn't seem to be a method corresponding to that.

Comment: who is calling `test()`? It seems to be running on the main thread... so it will execute first because the other threads have to wait 2 seconds for each print

Comment: regarding update - you can't do that without race conditions. The example is strange in that you create threads but then force them to run serially because of the lock - there was no need for the thread. If you want them to run in parallel, check out the multiprocessing ThreadPool object or create a queue to hold thread results.

Answer (score 1):

When using ill-defined internal functions like _is_owned, its best to look at the source:

```
def _is_owned(self):
    # Return True if lock is owned by current_thread.
    # This method is called only if __lock doesn't have _is_owned().
```

The main thread doesn't own the lock so the function returns false.

**Update**

If you just want to wait for the threads to finish, you don't need an RLock object at all. Just use the join() method:

```
def func(): 
    for i in range(3): 
        time.sleep(2)
        print(i)
    return

def test(): 
    threads = []
    for i in range(3): 
        time.sleep(1)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    return 'finished'

test()
```

Comment: I see, in that case I don't really know how to do what I'm trying to do , but let me update my question.